# TextureView with transparency

Tags: android, android-textureview

Is it possible to have a TextureView that has transparency, so that views below it (z-order) are visible?

IOW parts of the TextureView are transparent, and the view that the TextureView is on top of shows through.

Comment: Sounds possible! Did you tried to do so by setting alpha?

Answer (score 21):

You should use this API of TextureView.

TextureView.setOpaque(false);

It works fine!